# How to get all subclasses of a class in Dart?

Tags: oop, dart, dart-mirrors

For given example:

```dart
class Base {
    static abstract void foo();
}

class ChildA extends Base{
    static void foo(){};
}

class ChildB extends Base{
    static void foo(){};
}
```

I would like to find all subclasses of "Base" (to call foo on each).
I need to find this at build time (run time not required).
Only idea I have is to use reflections. But i don't know how to access class from ClassMirror?

This is what i have so far:

```dart
final mirror = currentMirrorSystem();
mirror.libraries.forEach((uri, libMirror) {
    libMirror.classes.forEach((name, ClassMirror classMirror) {
        try {
            while ((classMirror = classMirror.superclass) != null) {
                if (MirrorSystem.getName(classMirror.qualifiedName) == ".Base") {
                    //this is the classMirror of class i want
                    //but i have no idea how to access it 
                    //or how to call foo() on it
                    print(classMirror);
                    print(classMirror.simpleName.toString());
                }
            }

        } catch(e) {
            print(e);
        }
    });
});
```

As mentioned I don't need this at run time so maybe a totally different approach would solve this problem. If not, question is: how do I call foo()?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, maybe SO related feature works better than search or maybe my research was not hard enough but anyhow I have found this:

[Find all subclasses in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150437/find-all-subclasses-in-dart)

Answers there also suggested to use mirrors.
So to answer my own question a way to call static method foo is to use invoke method:

```
classMirror.invoke(#foo, []);
```

But this still is probably not an optimal solution, maybe there is a better way to do this at build time?

Comment: Looks like you've solved your issue ;) Apparently it is also possible to use "source mirrors" on source code without actually loading it into the vm. But I haven't seen anything published on how to use this. The code for this is probably buried in the dart2js source. You could look at the docgen tool for an example of how to use this. There has also been talk about "mirror builders" which let you use the mirror api to extend and modify programs. But for the moment - I think what you're doing is probably the best way. i.e. find the classes at build time, and then generate source code to include

Comment: You can call a static method as Function.apply(ClassB.foo, []); which doesn't require mirrors. But if you want to dynamically get the method from each subclass, that will need mirrors.