# dart, given an instance of a class is it possible to get a list of all the types it inherits from in ascending order?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

if I have:

```dart
List<Type> getInheritanceStructure(){
    // TODO
}

class A{
}
class B extends A{
}
class C extends B{
}

var c = new C();

List<Type> types = getInheritanceStructure(c);

types.forEach((type) => print(type));

//should print out:
C
B
A
Object
```

is it possible to get a list of Types like this?

Comment: My answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743346 does something similar. It looks up all base classes if it finds a static method of a given name. This should get you started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class mirror, from there you can walk through all the superclasses.

```dart
List<Type> getInheritanceStructure(Object o){
    ClassMirror baseClass = reflectClass(o.runtimeType);
    return walkSuperclasses(baseClass);
}

List<Type> walkSuperclasses(ClassMirror cm) {
    List<Type> l = [];
    l.add(cm.reflectedType);
    if(cm.superclass != null) {
        l.addAll(walkSuperclasses(cm.superclass));
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a difference between using `reflectClass(o.runtimeType)` and `reflect(o).type` ?

Comment: Not in this example, but apparently there is a difference. From the Dartdocs for `InstanceMirror.type`: "The class of the reflectee may differ from the object returned by invoking [runtimeType] on the reflectee". I have no idea under what circumstances this has any effect tough, sorry.

Comment: yeh that's what I read and prompted my question, thanks for the info any way.

Comment: @0xor1 I found an example where it differs - try both methods for a variable of type `String` or `int`, for example. Or with generics, the `o.runtimeType` method fails.