# Get all subclasses in dart

Tags: server, dart, dart-mirrors

I am trying to get all the subclasses of a given class following this post [Find all subclasses in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150437/find-all-subclasses-in-dart) like this:

```
import 'dart:mirrors';
class A {}
class B extends A{}

List<Type> getSubclasses(Type type) {
    List<Type> subClasses = [];
    MirrorSystem mirrorSystem = currentMirrorSystem();

    // NoSuchMethodError: Class '_LocalLibraryMirror' has no instance getter 'classes'. ???
    mirrorSystem.isolate.rootLibrary.classes.forEach((s, c) {
        if (c.superclass == type) {
            subClasses.add(c);
        }
    });
    return subClasses;
}

main() {
    var result = getSubclasses(A);
    print(result);
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

`Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class '_LocalLibraryMirror' has no instance getter 'classes'.
Receiver: Instance of '_LocalLibraryMirror'
Tried calling: classes`

The dart team probably removed that `classes` form the `LibraryMirror`, Does anybody knows any alternative?

I am using dart version: 1.24.3

Comment: This matches the documentation: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-mirrors/LibraryMirror-class.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Randal's suggestion, I could fix my problem with the following code:

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

List<ClassMirror> findSubClasses(Type type) {
    ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(type);

    return currentMirrorSystem()
        .libraries
        .values
        .expand((lib) => lib.declarations.values)
        .where((lib) {
            return lib is ClassMirror &&
            lib.isSubclassOf(classMirror) &&
            lib != classMirror;
        }).toList();
}
```

Hopefully this can help someone