# Flutter - How to use data from equal built classes?

Tags: flutter, class

I want to build an app for my pupil which generates tasks out of sentence blocks.
For example I created two classes, apple and pear, with nearly the same structure. They return a question built out of the sentence blocks which are defined in the classes. In both classes is a GenerateQuestion()-function for that.
Now I want to build some kind of *overclass*, which picks a random class of i.e. apple or pear and then returns the strings from the functions. The functions names are the same, but I can't figure out how to get data from a random choosen class. Hoping for help. Thanks in advance.

Update: Here is the code I wrote so far (I tried to translate it properly):

```
import 'dart:math';

 int randomminmax1 = 0;
 int randomminmax2 = 0;
 int randomminmax3 = 0;

 List classes = [apple, pear];

 class overClass {

   static pickClass(){
     int randomClassItem = Random().nextInt(classes.length);
     print(classes[randomClassItem]);
     return classes[randomClassItem];
   }
 }

class apple {

  static String giveQuestion()  {

    randomminmax1 = 2 + Random().nextInt(15 - 2);
    randomminmax2 = randomminmax1 * (2+Random().nextInt(12 - 2));
    randomminmax3 = 2 + Random().nextInt(30 - 2);

     List value_1 = [" boxes", " bags", " bucket"];
     List verbs = ["cost","have a price of", "are offered for"];
     List value_2 = ["Euro"];
     List questionWords = [""];

     int randomIndexValue1 = Random().nextInt(value_1.length);
     int randomIndexVerbs = Random().nextInt(verbs.length);
     int randomIndexValue2 = Random().nextInt(value_2.length);
     String value = randomminmax1.toString() + value_1[randomIndexValue1].toString() + " apples" +  verbs[randomIndexVerbs].toString() + " " + randomminmax2.toString() + " " + value_2[randomIndexValue2].toString() + ".\n";
     String question = "How much are " + randomminmax3.toString() + value_1[randomIndexValue1].toString() + "?\n";
    return value + question;
  }

  static String giveAnswer(){
    double result = (randomminmax2/randomminmax1)*randomminmax3;
    return result.toStringAsFixed(2) + " Euro.";
  }
}

class pear {

  static String giveQuestion() {
    randomminmax1 = 2 + Random().nextInt(15 - 2);
    randomminmax2 = randomminmax1 * (2+Random().nextInt(12 - 2));
    randomminmax3 = 2 + Random().nextInt(30 - 2);

   List value_1 = [" boxes", " bags", " bucket"];
     List verbs = ["cost","have a price of", "are offered for"];
     List value_2 = ["Euro"];
     List questionWords = [""];

     int randomIndexValue1 = Random().nextInt(value_1.length);
     int randomIndexVerbs = Random().nextInt(verbs.length);
     int randomIndexValue2 = Random().nextInt(value_2.length);
     String value = randomminmax1.toString() + value_1[randomIndexValue1].toString() + " pears" +  verbs[randomIndexVerbs].toString() + " " + randomminmax2.toString() + " " + value_2[randomIndexValue2].toString() + ".\n";
     String question = "How much are " + randomminmax3.toString() + value_1[randomIndexValue1].toString() + "?\n";
    return value + question;
  }

  static String giveAnswer(){
    double result = (randomminmax2/randomminmax1)*randomminmax3;
    return result.toStringAsFixed(2) + " Euro.";
  }
}

  static String giveAnswer(){
    double result = (randomminmax2/randomminmax1)*randomminmax3;
    return result.toStringAsFixed(2) + " Euro.";
  }
}
```

Comment: Present the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create a superclass that all question classes will inherit and then get the subclasses and programmatically call functions. Try to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053555/get-all-subclasses-in-dart)

Comment: Thanks so far! You solved it by creating if-statements. But I want to extend the two existing classes by numerous more. Is it possible to pick one of these classes randomly and get the question without putting all of the single question-functions of the classes into an if-statement?

Answer (score 0):

At least I managed to give my values directly from the classes into the list. But then I got problems with the int-variables, which were built wrong.

My "solution": I converted my classes into isolated flutter widgets, which works fine, except the problem that I'm not able to put the widgets into a list, from where they are picked randomly...but therefore I'll write a new post.

Thank you Moustapha for your help (the superclass idea sounds good, but way too hard to code for me) ;)!